# How to get PHP 64 Bit working and enabled on 64 Bit Apache in Windows 7 64?

Tags: php, apache, windows-7, 64-bit

I have installed PHP 5.5 64 Bit, as well as Apache 2.4 64Bit on my Windows 7 64 bit PC, bit MAX_INT is still displaying a 32 bit number (2147483647). The whole point of me doing these installations was to increase MAX_INT.

I cannot seem to find any info on this, so any help with getting PHP running as 64 Bit would be much appreceated.

Comment: To quote windows.php.net => "x86_64 Builds
The x64 builds of PHP for Windows should be considered experimental, and do not yet provide 64-bit integer or large file support. Please see this post for work ongoing to improve these builds., so it looks like a no go....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems only solution is to bypass Windows. Install VirtualBox with a 64 bit version of Linux, Apache and PHP 64 Bits, then at least it works.

I had Ubuntu 64Bit installed and get a MAX_INT of 9223372036854775807. Not ideal, as moving servers is a schlep, but it's much better and worth it in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Could I suggest, say, [WAMP Server 64 bit](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)? The problem you might be having is the build of Apache. I don't think there's an official build of Apache 64 bit for Windows.

Comment: Hmmm, I installed httpd-2.4.6-win64-VC11.zip from http://www.apachelounge.com/download/. After being with Apache for so many years I am pretty reluctant to change, but will do so if I don't find a solution soon. Thanks

Comment: My apologies. WAMP = Windows **Apache** MySQL PHP. It's all the packages rolled into one stable service. I personally find it better to do Windows this way unless you're running Windows Server. I use Easy PHP but I think all their builds are 32 bit.

Comment: I hear you. If anyone can confirm that the latest WAMP install can give a 64 Bit MAX_INT on Win7 I'll go for it.

Answer (score 0):

Now you've a chance to test upcoming PHP7 - http://windows.php.net/downloads/snaps/master/ with full 64-bit support.

Comment: Thanks for the tip :) One of these days, when and if time permits, I'll have a look.... but no rush as it's still way off of being put on a production server methinks.

Comment: I wouldn't say so. The final is expected this year. Should you've found some bugs with your use case, so the "production" could come closer :)

Comment: Hmm, most servers I work on run 5.3. To jump to 7 anytime soon seems wishful thinking. Having said that, I hear you, and do like to keep up to date with php, so will install it soon I am sure. b.t.w. The links are pretty intimidating (which one to download). Do you per chance have a suggestion as to which file/s to download (from within the snapshot folders)?

Comment: Oh, it's a pain to hear "5.3" in relation with "work" \0. You can just take the latest x64 build by date, fe http://windows.php.net/downloads/snaps/master/r770a462/php-master-nts-windows-vc11-x64-r770a462.zip . To test integers it's enough to run some CLI snippets of interest like php.exe -r "var_dump(PHP_INT_MAX);" or a script. CGI should work on any 64-bit host, with Apache ensure it's a VC11 build and using php7_module. And yeah - from 5.3 to 7 is quite a jump, some BC is expected, though all the tasty 64-bit (ints, dates, files, etc).